# Fossil repository on Squarespace

Tags: version-control, repository, hosting, fossil, squarespace

Does anyone know how or if it is possible to host a Fossil repository on a Squarespace blog site? I'm still working on learning Java for Android and don't need to take a diversion into becoming a Fossil or web guru right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seriously doubt it. It would require that you be able to run the Fossil executable on their Web servers; and considering that inserting a bit of HTML is an "advanced feature", they don't look like the hosting company that will let you do that.

But you could ask their [tech support](http://help.squarespace.com).

If you want to host one or more Fossil repositories, I recommend setting up an account at [Chisel](http://chiselapp.com), which hosts Fossil repositories; it's free and very simple to set up.

Comment: I just got an email notification that Chisel is shutting down May 1st, 2013.

Comment: So did I; there's currently [some discussion](http://www.mail-archive.com/fossil-users@lists.fossil-scm.org/msg11547.html) about setting up an alternative on the [fossil-users](http://www.mail-archive.com/fossil-users@lists.fossil-scm.org/) mailing list.

Comment: **Update**: Chisel hasn't shut down after all; a new owner has stepped up and taken over the hosting.